# How automatic xAxis labels rotation in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I use Highchart to draw my charts. I use :

```
xAxis: {

            labels: {
              rotation: -45,
             align: 'top'
            },
            categories: xAxisLabel
        },
```

for rotate the xaxis labels when number of labels are large.
But i want that labels automatically rotate when number of labels are large.
Is there any way to do this?
How can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highchart autorotate by default. You can use:

```
xAxis: {
        labels: {
            autoRotation: [-10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90]
        }
    },
```

see example in this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-autorotation-0-90/

or by default:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-autorotation-default/